# Used size in root directory is higher than the actual consumption

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system, redhat, rhel

used size of root directory is 13G as per the df -kh. but when i checked the individual size of the files and folder of root, the size is around 3G. where is the remaining files/folders located in root directory.
Below some outputs for reference,

```
[root@adair01 opt]# df -kh
Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root          66G   13G   51G  20% /


[root@adair01 var]# du -sch /*
0   /bin
225M    /boot
0   /dev
41M /etc
148K    /export
156K    /home
0   /lib
0   /lib64
16K /lost+found
4.0K    /media
0   /misc
4.0K    /mnt
0   /net
1.5G    /opt
du: cannot access ‘/proc/30925/task/30925/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/30925/task/30925/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/30925/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/30925/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
0   /proc
228K    /root
42M /run
0   /sbin
4.0K    /srv
0   /sys
1.1M    /tmp
1.2G    /usr
```

Comment: Found the culprit file thats consuming the 9.5G space , took one backup of the root file system, from that backup ,came to know that "net" folder consumed 9.5G but in the server the net folder is empty.

Comment: One other way the space in use can be larger than the space you can see being used is if a large (usually growing) file has been deleted, but a program still has it open (often as a log file — hence usually growing as new messages are logged to it).  The space will be freed as soon as the last process with the file open dies (or closes the file).

Comment: Now i narrowed down to /net folder where the junk files aer stuck. but now /net folder is used as mount point for "-hosts" with autofs filesystem.
-hosts on /net type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=13,pgrp=1845,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,indirect,pipe_ino=25548)
i know i can unmount this folder and delete the junk file. but after that i want to revert to this same mounting . i am unable to mount "-hosts".